# Self-check OS X code signature

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an OS X objective-c application that is signed.  I would like to check if the code signature is valid, then perform an action if it isn't, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Code Signing Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/Reference/reference.html). This is not officially supported on 10.5, but there is a [trick](http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-cdsa/2009/Oct/msg00007.html).